# How can I change x-axis position in dygraph?

Tags: javascript, css, html, dygraphs

I am new to dygraph and I have one issue: while creating dygraph using Javascript negative values of the y-axis are displayed above the x-axis 0 value.

Here is my code :

```
g6 = new Dygraph(document.getElementById('smooth-line'),
                   functionData,
                   {
                     labels: ['Year',  'First','Second'],
                     series: {

                         First: {
                         plotter: smoothPlotter,
                         color: '#26a69a ',
                         strokeWidth: 2
                       },
                       Second: {
                           plotter: smoothPlotter,
                           color: '#e57373 ',
                           strokeWidth: 2
                         }
                     },
                     legend: 'always',
                     gridLineColor: '#ddd',

                     //valueRange: [1.0, 30.0],
                     //yRangePad :[-20.0,20.0]
                   });
}
```

and the output of this code is:

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96qDd.png)

As in the image x-axis is below to -ve values of y-axis so how to set position of x-axis at the 0 value of y-axis?

Answer (score 0):

First a comment. Posting examples that are not self-contained takes a lot longer to troubleshoot.
This link: http://jsfiddle.net/yLytg398/1/ provides a reasonable approximation to your code that can be tested.

You actually had the solution already in your code, [valueRange](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#valueRange) is what you need. You can even use `valueRange: [0, null]` to automatically calculate the upper bound.

Correction: I just realized that you actually wanted to have the x axis with labels moved into the middle of the graph, my solution does not address this, but for your example picture it still works, because valueRange can set the lower end of the y range to zero, so that the x axis is at y = 0.